# Use git submodule update --init in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, git-submodules, bitbucket-pipelines

I've searched through a lot of the other related posts but haven't found a solution. I have my own private laradock repo that I'm using as a submodule in my git repo. I have the following bitbucket-pipeline.yml file:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
            - pip
            - composer
          name: Install server libs. Download and install composer. Build image, push to aws ecr, then deploy
          script:
            ...
            - git submodule update --init --recursive
            ...
```

When I run the pipeline I get the following error:

```
+ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'laradock' (https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/laradock.git) registered for path 'laradock'
Cloning into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/laradock'...
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://xxxx@bitbucket.org': No such device or address
fatal: clone of 'https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/laradock.git' into submodule path '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/laradock' failed
```

I've tried adding ssh keys to access keys. This was working until this morning. Any help would be great.

Comment: SSH keys are completely irrelevant for HTTPS-based connections, and you're specifying an HTTPS-based connection. Do you have the relevant password in the Pipelines variables?

Comment: I don't have the password in the pipeline vars. This was working until a couple days ago. I wonder if Bitbucket changed something on their end.

Answer (score 1):

If it requires password for an HTTPS URL, that means it is a private repository which requires credentials.

If you have access to the parent repo (which includes the laradock submodule), you might want to edit the `.gitmodules` and use SSH URLS, if you are [using SSH in your Bitbucket pipeline](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-can-I-use-SSH-in-Bitbucket-Pipelines/qaq-p/347345).

Note: there is an [incident](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/rtw1q41b2yqk) [in progress](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/) on BitBucket side which could explain why any HTTPS clone would fail at the moment

[image: BitBucket pipeline]

Comment: The bitbucket pipeline docker container is what is failing to gain access. I tried with the ssh key but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Chris I have edited the answer to mention the current Bitbucket outage.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in a way I don't like but it works for now. I had to create an app password inside my bitbucket account in the access management section. I then changed the url inside my .gitmodules to include my username and app password. This really sucks because my username and app password are now inside the pipeline logs. Of course I can revoke that password at anytime. I didn't want to go this route but I couldn't get anything else to work. Anybody have a better solution I'm all ears, IE username and password inside repo vars.

Comment: At least use a PAT instead of your actual account password: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with the issue...https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/rtw1q41b2yqk They say "We are investigating an incident with Bitbucket git and mercurial over HTTPs. Pipelines are affected as well. The team is working to restore the service ASAP.
Posted 35 minutes ago. Oct 01, 2019 - 14:24 UTC"